# Python VLookup get output without merge

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, vlookup

I have 2 data sets,and I need to get the `'MAKE'` column based on the `'MODEL'` 
but the results column in a separate dataframe (Not merge with existing dataframe)

I could merge the data by using below code,

```
def vlookup_sample():

    df1 = pd.read_excel('tb1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
    df2 = pd.read_excel('tb2.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')

    df = pd.merge(df1, df2[['MODEL', 'MAKE']], on='MODEL', how='left')
    df["MAKE"].fillna("<n/a>", inplace=True)

    print df
```

**Dataset 1**

```
ID  MODEL   REQUESTS    ORDERS
1   Golf    123          4
2   Passat  34           5
3   Model 3 500          8
4   M3      5            0
```

**Dataset2**

```
MODEL   TYPE    MAKE
Golf    Sedan   Volkswagen
M3      Coupe   BMW
Model 3 Sedan   Tesla
```

**Expected output:**

```
MAKE
 Volkswagen
 Nan
 Tesla
BMW
```

How do I get the result in to a separate data

Comment: `new_df = df1.merge(df2,on='MODEL',how='left').loc[:,['MAKE']]` ? that gives you a new dataframe

Comment: Thank you very much, Please write as answer , so that I can accept it and this will help for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same merge and call the `MAKE` column from the merge output using [`df.loc[]`](https://www.google.com/search?q=df+loc&rlz=1C1GCEU_enIN822IN823&oq=df+loc&aqs=chrome..69i57j0j69i65j69i60l3.1008j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8):

```
new_df = df1.merge(df2,on='MODEL',how='left').loc[:,['MAKE']]
#pd.merge(df1, df2[['MODEL', 'MAKE']], on='MODEL', how='left').loc[:,['MAKE']]
```

Comment: But doesn't this first create a copy of all columns in `df1` and only after making a copy takes a slice out of the new combined dataframe to retrieve `MAKE`?  Is there a way to do this without making this unnecessary copying of data?  Thank  you